# Clamping CIImage returns strange sizes

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to crop an image and extend the colors from the edges with clamping, but is returning a strange image size after that:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "frame_1")
var ciimage = CIImage(image: image!)

print("\(ciimage!.extent.width) x \(ciimage!.extent.height)")
// at this point it returns "480.0 x 360.0" that is ok

ciimage = ciimage!.clamping(to: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 480.0, height: 360.0))

print("\(ciimage!.extent.width) x \(ciimage!.extent.height)")
//now it returns two strange values: "1.79769313486232e+308 x 1.79769313486232e+308"
```

Shouldn't it return 480.0 and 360.0 after clamping? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: clamping:     /* Return a new infinite image by replicating the edge pixels of the receiver image. */

Comment: Any idea how can I do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: are you just trying to crop ?

Comment: Trying to crop, but add the clamping to the rest of the image. For example, if I crop the whole image but not the last 10 pixels/points from the bottom, I need that these 10 pixels to have that clamp technique.

Comment: tbh im not familiar with clamping as a concept im afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved the problem, cropping it after clamping:

```
ciimage = ciimage!.clamping(to: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 480, height: 360))

ciimage = ciimage!.cropping(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 360))
```

The result is what I expected.